# How to install i386 packages on Ubuntu on ARM-based Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have installed Ubuntu on a Nexus 7 (with an ARM processor). I want to install a DEB package made for i386 architecture.

Is that possible ? How should I proceed ?

Comment: 有帮徒, could you please tell us what package you would like to install ? If it is an open-source app, it may just be in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Conceivably, it should be possible to install and run any non-ARM binary by using emulation such as Qemu. Since emulation is effectively translation of the instruction set on-the-fly, I wonder if it's possible to ‘pre-translate’ the binaries to achieve a faster runtime speed. If it _is_ possible, it should happen automatically at installation, without relying on developers/packagers to have compiled the ARM version of every package.

Answer (score 2):

You can't install a i386 package on ARM, but it is very well possible that an ARM alternative exists or if source code is available you might be able to compile from sources.

Comment: x86 software won’t run on ARM (without an x86 emulator) but with Debian/Ubuntu’s `apt` it is very well possible to install packages from foreign architectures. I need some x86 libraries for a x86 binary blob I need to run. My problem is that ARM packages are on ports.ubuntu.com while i386/amd64 packages are on the main mirrors and `apt-get update` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, the i386 package likely won't run, but if you want to install it anyway, you can run

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i /path/to/package.deb
```