# Getting ia32-libs-gtk

Tags: 13.04, package-management

I am testing Ubuntu 13.04 ARM on my Android phone. I want to try using Cisco Packet Tracer, I have installed it but it needs ia32-libs-gtk package to work. I tried to do

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk:i386
```

but still I can't get that package because "E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-gtk". I am new at using Ubuntu. I was "Googling" about that problem like for half an hour but what I mostly saw is some old (~2011) topics not really helping. How can I install that package?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

I had to add `gtk2-engines-murrine:i386` because a theme I was using required it and skype looked ugly without it. Using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Hi! sorry for no response, some time passed but now I need to get CPT working on Ubuntu 13.10 this time. Your command doesn't work (Unable to locate package), also tried solutions from here:
http://www.dedunu.info/2013/12/installing-cisco-packet-tracer-601-on.html
but it always ended with package not being able to be located. Can you please help me? :)

Comment: Hmm... Have you seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230151/how-to-install-i386-packages-on-ubuntu-on-arm-based-nexus-7)?

Comment: this question is not related to my problem because I have already installed Cisco Packet Tracer - but it's not starting.

Comment: @TheReduxPL I know this is old, and i'm not trying to necro-rez, but did you get it working? I've got the same problem.