# How to install i386/amd64 packages on ARM or any other arch from Ubuntu Ports

Tags: apt, dependencies, raspberrypi, arm, multiarch

I need to run some x86 binary with QEMU on a Raspberry Pi (`armhf` port, ARMv7) to make a printer work with Canon’s crappy binary UFRII drivers. How to just install its x86 dependencies on `armhf` (*not* how to run them)?

I can install the x86 binary with:

```
root@raspberry-pi:~# dpkg --force-architecture -i /tmp/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.10-1_i386.deb
```

but then `apt` keeps complaining that its dependencies are missing. I’ll probably actually need them to run the UFRII converter—so I’d really like to install the i386 dependencies via `apt`.

I can add the `i386` architecture but `apt-get update` fails to download some resources, probably because `armhf` resides on ports.ubuntu.com while x86 packages are on the main mirrors. (I’ve once successfully installed i386 packages on amd64 before.)

```
root@raspberry-pi:~# dpkg --add-architecture i386       
root@raspberry-pi:~# apt-get update                  
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Fetched 252 kB in 2s (112 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to fix this? I probably need to adjust/add something to `/etc/apt/sources.list` but that doesn’t contain the strings `i386`/`amd64`. So I don’t know where to start. This is my current sources file:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security multiverse
```

I found the question [How to install i386 packages on Ubuntu on ARM-based Nexus 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230151/how-to-install-i386-packages-on-ubuntu-on-arm-based-nexus-7) but people there just answer that running x86 on ARM isn’t possible. That’s true but not the correct answer to the original question.

**Update:** This is the output of `dpkg-deb` for the desired driver package including its 1st level dependencies:

```
root@raspberry-pi:~# dpkg-deb --info /tmp/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.10-1_i386.deb 
 new Debian package, version 2.0.
 size 21503884 bytes: control archive=20743 bytes.
    2058 bytes,    16 lines      control              
   62636 bytes,   896 lines      md5sums              
     339 bytes,    17 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
      90 bytes,     9 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/sh
 Package: cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk
 Version: 5.10-1
 Section: net
 Priority: optional
 Architecture: i386
 Depends: cupsys | cups, libcups2 | libcupsys2 (>= 1.2.7)
 Conflicts: cnrcupsiradv715zk, cnrcupsiradv615zk, cnrcupsiradv525zk, cnrcupsiradv7153zk, cnrcupsiradv6153zk, cnrcupsiradv5253zk, cnrcupsiradv85053zk, cnrcupsiradv85853zk, cnrcupsiradv65753zk, cnrcupsiradv65553zk, cnrcupsiradvc35203zk, cnrcupsiradvc35253zk, cnrcupsiradvc75803zk, cnrcupsiradvc75653zk, cnrcupsiradvc2563zk, cnrcupsiradvc55353zk, cnrcupsiradvc55503zk, cnrcupsiradv45453zk, cnrcupsiradv45253zk, cnrcupsiradvc4753zk, cnrcupswg7000zk, cnrcupswg7000zzk, cnrcupslbp853czk, cnrcupslbp852czk, cnrcupsd1600zk
 Replaces: cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us, cnrdrvcups-lipslx, cnrcupsiradv715zk, cnrcupsiradv615zk, cnrcupsiradv525zk, cnrcupsiradv7153zk, cnrcupsiradv6153zk, cnrcupsiradv5253zk, cnrcupsiradv85053zk, cnrcupsiradv85853zk, cnrcupsiradv65753zk, cnrcupsiradv65553zk, cnrcupsiradvc35203zk, cnrcupsiradvc35253zk, cnrcupsiradvc75803zk, cnrcupsiradvc75653zk, cnrcupsiradvc2563zk, cnrcupsiradvc55353zk, cnrcupsiradvc55503zk, cnrcupsiradv45453zk, cnrcupsiradv45253zk, cnrcupsiradvc4753zk, cnrcupswg7000zk, cnrcupswg7000zzk, cnrcupslbp853czk, cnrcupslbp852czk, cnrcupsd1600zk
 Provides: cnrcupsiradv715zk, cnrcupsiradv615zk, cnrcupsiradv525zk, cnrcupsiradv7153zk, cnrcupsiradv6153zk, cnrcupsiradv5253zk, cnrcupsiradv85053zk, cnrcupsiradv85853zk, cnrcupsiradv65753zk, cnrcupsiradv65553zk, cnrcupsiradvc35203zk, cnrcupsiradvc35253zk, cnrcupsiradvc75803zk, cnrcupsiradvc75653zk, cnrcupsiradvc2563zk, cnrcupsiradvc55353zk, cnrcupsiradvc55503zk, cnrcupsiradv45453zk, cnrcupsiradv45253zk, cnrcupsiradvc4753zk, cnrcupswg7000zk, cnrcupswg7000zzk, cnrcupslbp853czk, cnrcupslbp852czk, cnrcupsd1600zk
 Installed-Size: 76096
 Maintainer: CANON INC. <sup-debian@mail.canon>
 Source: cnrdrvcups-lb
 Description: Canon UFR2 Printer Driver for Linux
  Canon UFR2 Printer Driver for Linux.
  This UFR2 printer driver provides printing functions for Canon LBP/iR
  printers operating under the CUPS (Common UNIX Printing System) environment.
```

Comment: Different architectures can have different package versions & deps, eg. look up `mysql-server-5.7` for bionic and you'll note different version PLUS different dependency requirements for different architectures (but all for current bionic releases). x86/i386 & x86_64/amd64 are kept matching - but this doesn't apply to different architectures like armhf & x86/i386, let alone s390 & others... ie *dep-hell* is to be expected.  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mysql-server-5.7 *used only as example, thought of this question when commenting on another*..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I later found out by trial & error that you need to make the default entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` more specific:

```
dpkg --add-architecture 'i386'

# replace 'deb' with 'deb [arch=armhf]'
sed 's/^deb http/deb [arch=armhf] http/' -i '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Add a file like `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/i386.list` with the x86 mirror servers:

```
deb [arch=i386] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security  main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=i386]  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal           main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=i386]  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates   main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=i386]  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

```
apt-get update
```

I could successfully install and run the UFRII driver with:

```
apt-get install qemu-user

# undeclared dependencies of UFRII driver package
apt-get install  libcupsimage2:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 ghostscript:i386

apt-get install /path/to/ufrii_driver.deb
```

Comment: Could you please expand? I tried the same `sources.list` and same `cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.10-1_i386.deb` without any luck. I get back `Package 'libcupsimaage2:i386' has no installation candidate` Thanks

Comment: I modified `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports` to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`, but getting a list of unmet dependencies, failing to install

Comment: @user424174 Thank you for raising the issue! I looked into my deployment script and found that I had not documented the additional apt sources. You need your original ARM packages, of course, and additionally different servers for i386 alias x86. Do it work with that?

Comment: I'm pleased to say it works! I installed a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Pi 2 to run the test, added the `i386.list` installed `cups` (armhf) and `dpkg -i cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.10-1_i386.deb`. The driver was found in cups and I managed to print! Amazing! The only usability issue I find now is that it is slow. and the certain cores goes up to 100% when rendering. A 2-page Google webpage would render for 2 minutes to before it starts to print. Once print starts, it finishes quick.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. Converting documents in the UFRII format utilizes x86 emulation which is slow on its own while that Raspberry Pi already isn’t a fast computer. Printing multiple copies is relatively faster (per page) because conversion happens only once.

Comment: I assume you're running on a Pi 2 like I am? Appreciate all the efforts and quick responses.

Comment: Mine is `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2` as reported from `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model`

Comment: As you have a Pi 3, if you have a spare SD card, could you give ARM64 distro a try? Such as the Pi OS ARM64 variant and Canon driver `cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.30-1_arm64.deb`. I wonder if that'd install and speed things up by processing without qemu and i386 packages.

Comment: Ok, I didn’t know I could run a 64-bit OS. Interesting! This is the first Raspberry Pi I’ve ever used and I was happy I got it working with the printer driver at all. The thing is now running in "production" and I won’t spend the time for this research now. Maybe I'll come back to this later.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer here is how I setup a Canon MF4570dw on a RPI3 running PI OS 64 bit https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120630/install-canon-printer-in-cups-on-rpi3

Comment: Awesome @Ionut and Daniel convinced me to upgrade my Pi 2 to Pi 3! Well done!

Comment: I think you should go for a RPI4, it has more RAM and Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: @Ionut got a cheapish Pi 3 just for the job. I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed on it, `cups` and `cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.30-1_arm64.deb` but it didn't work straight away (failed with a render failure). However, after installing some of the known dependencies `libglade2-0 libjpeg62 libgcrypt20-dev libcupsimage2` it worked perfectly. Tested both printer locally plugged to Pi by USB as well as printer connected via Ethernet.