# Can't install i386 package(s)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, update-manager

This is not a duplicate question, I've followed the steps in the similar question that was posted on Ubuntu v. 18.04, but no solutions worked.

despite doing `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

this is returned when I try to install i386 packages or after updating the list.

````
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/hirsute-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/hirsute-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.```
````

Comment: Ubuntu removed support for i386 with version 20. Only some minor libraries are available, mostly for Steam.

Comment: So what do I do? I need it for Steam.

Comment: I think the issue may be that the *ARM ports repository* specifically does not provide i386 packages - they should still be available from mainstream x86 repositories. See for example [How to install i386/amd64 packages on ARM or any other arch from Ubuntu Ports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211022/how-to-install-i386-amd64-packages-on-arm-or-any-other-arch-from-ubuntu-ports)

Answer (score 2):

From: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation

To enable the installation of multiarch binaries, apt and dpkg need configuration changes. For example, if you have an amd64 system that you want to install i386 libraries onto, do the following:

- multiarch support is present from `dpkg` 1.16.2 (or 1.16.0 in Ubuntu) and `apt` 0.8.13.
- run `dpkg --add-architecture i386`
- run `apt-get update` to refresh the package cache with the newly added architecture
- to delete i386 run `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Comment: I did that like 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an `arm` system.

`i386` and `amd64` are not at http://ports.ubuntu.com;
They're are at http://archive.ubuntu.com/