# How to run a QT5 program compiled for i386 on ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, qt5

I have an old program compiled for an ubuntu 16.04 i386, I need to run it or recompile for i386 architecture in my new pc (change 32 to 64 bit is quite complicated in this code". I have an ubuntu 22.04.1 but I dont know how to run 32 bit program on 64 bit ubuntu

Comment: If you let us know what the program is (assuming it's open source or source available) someone may be able to provide you with a guide. Without knowing which program it is, the options may be many, or limited.

Comment: @popey It is not an open source code, but the problem will be the same as if I did with a Hello World Window with some push buttons and tables...

Comment: So your real question is how can you run a 32 bit program on a 64 bit OS?

Comment: No, it isn't the same. Dependencies, how it's built (cmake vs make or whatever) and so on makes it different. I might have recommended bundling in a snap or lxc or docker, depending on what it was.

Comment: @popey it is a c++ Program and it uses a lot of qt libs and only libusb lib. It uses make for build

Comment: @David yes it is. I do not need to compile it...

Comment: What happens if you just run it? What does it complain about? 32-bit code can run on 64-bit installs. But some of the 32-bit libraries it may depend on have been removed, making this problem harder to solve.

Comment: @popey 
`bash: ./motor No such file or directory`
so I did 
`ls -la 
-rxwxr-xr-x 1 user user 7414460 Feb 14 15:15 motor`

Comment: can you run `ldd ./motor` and see what libraries it's after?

Comment: @popey `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: Might need to use `strace` to see what it's after. If it's something you only need now and then, you could spin up a 32-bit 16.04 VM and run it there, but if you need it regularly, it's likely you're going to need to port to 64-bit or get someone else do to the port.

Comment: `No such file or directory` and `not a dynamic executable` likely mean you don't even have a loader for 32-bit executables (ex. `/lib32/ld-linux.so.2`) on your system - at a minimum, you will need to add the i386 architecture and install the libc6:i386 package I think. Then you will be able to see what other 32-bit dynamic libs are missing.

Comment: @steeldriver you where right
I finally got it. Simply run the following commands:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386`
I also installed the following packages from apt

`sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev:i386 qtmultimedia5-dev:i386`
Now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @JuanJose can you answer your own question? That will help other users in the future

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install i386 package(s)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350169/cant-install-i386-packages)

Comment: @NoElDr01ds No, It doesnt

Answer (score 2):

First

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

This allow my system to recognize which libraries the program needs.
Then, know libs needed.

```
ldd your_program_name
```

I needed a lot of Qt libs so I installed.

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev:i386 qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
```

That is all that I needed.