# Skipping acquire of configured file as repository doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: apt, updates

With `apt-get update` I got the error message:

```
Reading package lists... done   
N: Skipping acquire of configured file "main/binary-i386/Packages"   
as repository "https://repo.ckvsoft.at/ckvsoft jammy-ckvsoft-stable InRelease" doesn't support architecture 'i386'.
```

I have been looking in the apt directory but there is no File with "main/binary-i386/Packages".
This is a newly build system that is fully 64-bit.

I found that Google Chrome could be responsible, but there is no repository that points to Google.

Comment: Such nach der betreffenden Datei under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` und füge nach dem deb [arch=amd64] ein.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to enable i386 to get rid of the error, instead of deleting i386. [Can't install i386 package(s)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1350169/1004020) says `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, assuming your 64-bit system is Intel/AMD not ARM. It is likely that your "ckvsoft" vendor wants to continue shipping 32-bit software, and you want to install it.

If you really want to remove i386 together with this "ckvsoft" thing:

```bash
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d # This is the one of many apt directories you seek
grep ckvsoft -r .
sudo rm ./name-of-the-file.list
# Depending on how you installed it,
# there might be cleaner ways like
# `apt remove name_of_package_for_the_list` or
# https://askubuntu.com/q/307/1004020
# that remove the gpg key as well
# but they require more assumptions

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```