# apt-get update i386 Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, steam

Info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I am trying to install a server for Valheim steam game, and I need i386 packages.

I added the i386 architecture but now when I do `apt-get update` I get this

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't know how to solve it.

I tried to do `apt-get dist-upgrade` but didn't work.

My  `/etc/apt/sources.list` has:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse
```

Don't tell me to do

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

I know that that solve the problem to do `apt-get update` but I need i386 architecture.

Comment: I'm trying that but all the distribution I write on "/etc/apt/sources.list" have the same issue :(

Comment: What is your hardware's *native* architecture (ex. `uname -m`)? is it by any chance an ARM-based system?

Comment: uname -m give me "aarch64"

Comment: i386 is not a compatible architecture with aarch64 (arm64), have you added an intel/amd i386 compatible cpu to your box? as normally arm64 boxes don't provide that.   i386 is also not found in ports (it's not a port; thus your issue; however even if you corrected that, you'd not achieve anything unless you've got an i386 cpu in your box)

Comment: I'm ussing a raspberry pi 4, and I installed ubuntu server 20.04.
So I have to use something like a virtual machine in my raspberry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install i386 packages on Ubuntu on ARM-based Nexus 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230151/how-to-install-i386-packages-on-ubuntu-on-arm-based-nexus-7)  ; there is a better duplicate but I didn't find it sorry

Comment: Steam runs on Raspbian because Valve did some serious work on compatibility. Valve has not contributed that work to Ubuntu, so Steam currently won't work on a Pi running Ubuntu.

Comment: So if I want to use i386 I have to install Raspbian?

Comment: You won't have `i386` on this hardware either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems like a classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Your actual problem seems to be that Steam does not run on your Pi running Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, you have been sidetracked into asking an irrelevant question about i386 libraries.

- Steam runs on Raspbian because Valve did some serious work on compatibility. Valve has not contributed that work to Ubuntu, so Steam currently won't work on a Pi running Ubuntu. This is a Valve decision, not an Ubuntu decision.
- i386 libraries for steam are a matter for amd64 systems (most Desktops). But on RPIs, those libraries are part of the Valve compatibility software. RPis cannot run i386 software without (high resource) emulation.